# Javascript How to convert a non-UTC Date string into the Date object?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a string "2017-01-05T15:03:25.21" which is already the exact time in my timezone. (eg: +8)
How to convert this string into the Date Object?
The reason of asking this is that, the Date class seems to accept a 'UTC Date String' only. If i directly do this:

```
var strDateTime = "2017-01-05T15:03:25.21";
var myDate = new Date(strDateTime);

//myDate will have another redundant time-zone offset.
```

How to convert this properly?

Comment: You could use moment.js or other dedicated library - it's much easier than having to do it manually, because JS at the moment has poor native support of date-time logic.

Comment: please accept my answer as correct if it's helpful :)

Comment: @Ovidiu Dolha thanks for mentioning this, as i thought i was missing sth.

Comment: @Lukas Liesis, i have upvoted :) let me observe a while.

Comment: In general, you should never parse strings with the *Date* constructor (or *Date.parse*, they are equivalent for parsing). From ES5 onward, ISO 8601 format strings are **usually** correctly parsed with the exception of the date only form, where parsing is inconsistent with ISO 8601: it's treated as UTC rather than local. To be safe, **always** manually parse strings (a library can help, but a bespoke function need only be 3 or 4 lines of code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to convert this properly?

Implementations consistent with ECMAScript ed 5 (ES5) and later will parse the string correctly with either the Date constructor or Date.parse, so:

```
var strDateTime = "2017-01-05T15:03:25.21";
var myDate = new Date(strDateTime);
```

Will produce a date for 5 Jan 2017 3:03:25.21 PM in the local timezone.

However, it's not recommended to do that given the general inconsistencies in parsing between implementations. Either a custom function or library should be used, e.g. using [fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha):

```
var myDate = fecha.parse(strDateTime, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SS")
```

From ES5 and later, ISO 8601 date and time strings are mostly parsed as specified in ISO 8601. The main differences are:

1. Date–only forms like "2016-12-12" are parsed as UTC rather than local
2. Only a "*simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format*" is supported, as detailed in [*ECMA-262 §20.3.1.6 Date Time String Format*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)

So given:

```
var s = "2017-01-05T15:03:25.21";
var d = new Date(s)
```

then *d* will be converted to a Date with a UTC time value based on the host system timezone setting. If your host is set to UTC+0800, then that is the timezone that is applied.

Date objects do not have a time zone. All they have is a single time value that represents milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Any related time zone information comes from the host. So the comment:

```
//myDate will have another redundant time-zone offset.
```

is incorrect. The host time zone setting will be used to determine the offset that is used to calculate the UTC time value, and also to calculate the local values returned by the *get** methods like *getFullYear*, *getMonth*, *getDate*, *getHours*, etc.

The string "2017-01-05T15:03:25.21" on a system with an offset of +0800 will generate a time value of 1483599805210, which represents 2017-01-05T07:03:25.21Z (i.e. UTC+0000).

If you wish to send a timestamp that represents a particular moment to clients in different time zones, then one of the following should suite.

Append the time zone to the string:

```
2017-01-05T15:03:25.21+0800
```

Use the UTC equivalent:

```
2017-01-05T07:03:25.21Z
```

Use a time value:

```
1483599805210
```

The last is generally preferred as `new Date(timevalue)` is supported by all implementations, is unambiguous and can be easily converted for use in other systems.

Comment: Thanks for your long explanation. Give me some time to digest your words. Understood from your message that removing the 'T' isn't compliant with the standards.

Comment: @zflaw—yep. Removing the T is allowed for in ISO 8601 in certain conditions, but not by ECMA-262. So implementations might decide that the missing T means it's not ISO 8601 and therefore fall back to whatever parsing they want (as does Firefox), or decide that it's invalid ISO 8601 and return an invalid date (as does Safari). Both are consistent with the standard, though the inconsistency itself is annoying. :-/

Comment: Allow me to ask, say if i want to go this way:
2017-01-05T15:03:25.21+0800

The last part "+0800" has to be computed by myself right?
(such as, using the function getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: @zflaw—yes, as long as you use the correct offset. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can add timezone to end of string like this:

```
var strDateTime = "2017-01-05T15:03:25.21"+"-08:00";
var myDate = new Date(strDateTime);
```

You can read more about valid date format here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: that sure is a great trick! (to append at the back)
to me, it is to add "+08:00".

Comment: There is no need to add the offset. If there is no offset, an ISO 8601 string is treated as local (in implementations consistent with ES5 and later).

Comment: @RobG if there is offset passed, my result is it adds another offset (as shown in my question).

Comment: @Lukas Liesis your answer and info provided are really appreciated. I chose another as it seems shorter and doesn't really the offset info.

Comment: @zflaw—I don't understand how "it adds another offset". If the host timezone is set to UTC+0800, then `new Date('2017-01-05T15:03:25.21')` and `new Date('2017-01-05T15:03:25.21+0800')` should produce identical results. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var strDateTime = "2017-01-05T15:03:25.21";
var myDate = new Date(strDateTime.replace('T', ' '));
```

OUTPUT for my timezone :
Thu Jan 05 2017 15:03:25 GMT+0200 (EET)

Comment: This is even better (without the need to get the offset)! Good one!

Comment: This answer should not be accepted. If the format "2017-01-05T15:03:25.21" is parsed at all (and some browsers wont), it will be parsed correctly as a local time (i.e. as if the offset for the host system were added). Removing the T simply makes it partially non–compliant with ISO 8601 and wholly non–compliant with ECMA-262, so browsers (like Safari) may return an invalid date on that basis.